# Why must equality constraints be affine in convex optimization?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In the convex constrained optimization problem:

\begin{align}
      & min \quad  f(x) \\        
      &  s.t \quad g_i(x) \leq 0 , \quad i = 1, ... m \\
      &  \quad \quad  h_j(x) = 0, \quad j = 1, ..., n
\end{align}

I don't understand why the equality constraints must be affine functions. There is another similiar question but I still don't get it.

If we define $h(x) = p(x) + c = 0$ in which, $p(x)$ is convex and $c \in \mathbb R$, $h(x)$ will be also convex as prove below:

\begin{align}
p(tx + (1-t)y) &\leq tp(x) +(1-t)p(y) \\
p(tx + (1-t)y) + c  &\leq tp(x) +(1-t)p(y) + tc + (1-t)c \\
p(tx + (1-t)y) + c&\leq t(p(x)+c) +(1-t)(p(y)+c) \\
h(tx + (1-t)y) &\leq th(x) +(1-t)h(y)
\end{align}

Comment: It has to be affine to guarantee the feasible set is convex set.


for example if $h(x) = x^2 - 1$ then feasible set consist of only two points  $\{ -1 , +1 \}$

Comment: $h (x) = 0$ is equivalent to $h (x) \leq 0$ and $h (x) \geq 0$. If $h$ is affine, then both $h (x) \leq 0$ and $h (x) \geq 0$ define convex sets. If $h$ is not affine, then it is impossible for both $h (x) \leq 0$ and $h (x) \geq 0$ to define convex sets.

Comment: Just a minor comment that this assumes that there are no hidden reductions in the representation. $z(x-y-z)=1, z^2=1, (z-2)^2=1$ is a convex set for instance. A problem with a nonconvex representation is not necessarily nonconvex geometrically.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg's comment is definitely not minor. It is *not* necessary for $h_i(x)$ to be affine or $g_i(x)$ to be convex for the feasible region described to be convex. For instance, $(x-2y)^2=0$ describes a convex set. Thus it's not even necessary to rely on the intersections of multiple equations as Johan has done. We place these conditions on $g$ and $h$ for _practical_ reasons: they facilitate the construction of useful analyses, proofs, and algorithms.

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2596938/in-convex-optimization-equality-constraints-must-be-linear-or-affine