# Example of convex nonlinear equality constraint

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I know that affine equalities such as

$$a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + a_3 x_3 = b_3$$

are convex. I'm wondering whether there are *nonlinear* equality constraints, for instance something like

$$a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + a_3 x_3 = b_3 + x^{2p},\quad p \in N$$

or even something like

$$x_1 = x_2^2$$

Are these kinds of equality constraint also convex? Can you give me any other example showing non-affine convex functions? Thanks!

Comment: Also this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2597545/why-must-equality-constraints-be-affine-in-convex-optimization#comment5382546_2597545

Comment: Dear Michael, thanks a lot!