# Convex minimization problem for finding global minimum of a function

Tags: numerical-methods, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

I want to minimize $f(x)$ w.r.t to some contraint $h(x)=0$ , here both $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ are convex functions. However, suppose I also know that the
function $f(x)$ have a unique global minimum at a point $x_u^*$ and $h(x_u^*) \gt 0$. I want to prove that i can find a global optimal point $x_c^*$ by solving convex problem of minimizing $f(x)$ subject to $h(x) \leq 0$.

Comment: I assume, since the problem is convex and the constraint is equality one that $ h \left( x \right) $ is linear. Is that right?

Comment: i dont think $h(x)$ needs to be linear.

Comment: In order to have a convex problem equality constraints must be linear.

Comment: I have familiar with examples where $f(x)$ is convex quadratic and $h(x)$ is monotonic, convex quadratic (for example $l_2$-norm), where your required result can be shown. But, I doubt if it is true in its generality. Is it possible for you to share how $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ looks like.

Comment: @heerathakur, See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2596938. Is your case the non classic case where the functions are not necessarily linear?